# List of countries that do not have psychiatric hospitals

Tags: medical, demographics

Where can I find a list of countries that do not have psychiatric hospitals? I've searched on Google and Wikipedia but could not find any links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a sortable list, but the WHO keeps track of the mental health institutions per country and has a report on each country here: http://www.who.int/mental_health/evidence/atlas/profiles/en/

They also provide a shaded map in their [atlas](http://www.who.int/mental_health/publications/mental_health_atlas_2011/en/) which I copied below. You'll have to look up the reports on the lightly shaded countries to check wether they have any mental healthcare facilities at all.

[image: Psychiatrists per population]